# How to correctly use Jena property

Tags: jena

I understand that I can retrieve an existing property from my model by using `model.getProperty`, for example:

```
Model model;
Property description_property = model.getProperty(NS.dcterms + "description");
```

But say I don't have the model available but want to create a local model I'm forced to use:

```
Property descriptionProperty= 
               ResourceFactory.createProperty(NS.dcterms + "description");
```

Can someone give a nice explanations of when and why to use `model.getProperty` vs `ResourceFactory.createProperty` and its implications.

Comment: For this particular case, you'd probably be better off using [`DC.description`](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/vocabulary/DC_11.html#description) if you don't care about the model associated with the property, and `DC.description.`[`inModel( model )`](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/Resource.html#inModel(com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model)) to get it in your model when you do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two forms are actually pretty much equivalent. The principle difference is that, when you do a `model.getXXX` to get a property or resource object, that object then contains a pointer back to the model against which it was created. This can be helpful, as in Jena it's really only the model objects that hold state. Java classes such as `Resource` and `Property` denote resource and property identities, but the real content is the triples (i.e. `Statement`s) in the model.

To make that concrete, if you do something like:

```
Resource s = ... ;
Property p = ... ;
RDFNode o = ... ;
p.getModel().addStatement( s, p, o );
```

that will succeed in your first case (i.e. with `Model.getProperty`) and fail in the second (i.e. `ResourceFactory`), since in the second case `getModel()` will return `null`. However, whether that's a practical concern in your application is something only you can say. I don't find it to be much of a problem in my code, to be honest.

Incidentally, you may like to know that Jena has a utility called [schemagen](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/tools/schemagen.html), which can auto-generate Java source code containing constants corresponding to the classes, properties and individuals in your ontology. It can be clearer and more maintainable than manually creating such constants in your code.

Comment: Nice explanation. 
The followup question is then, if adding properties this way is "real content":
iaModel.createResource( NS.lcx + "ContentItem/IA/" + iaeIdentifier ) 
 .addProperty( titleProperty, "a title" )
I dont understand difference using "addStatement" vs adding statement like above.

Comment: Basic answer: not much different. Jena has a bunch of different ways of achieving the same end; to that extent, it's not very opinionated about how you manage your models. If that's not enough of an explanation, please feel free to open up a new top-level question with a bit more detail in it.